# How to get rid of hairline between two divs in html/css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have two elements as close as I possibly can get them. If you're curious, the first is an scroll-to-top script that the user can click, and below it is a flat background. That hairline is really annoying me.

Any help is appreciated!

```css
/*SCROLL TO TOP*/
.scroll-top-wrapper img{
 width: 134px;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.border_background{

 background: #162a53;
 height: 416px;
}

...
```

```html
 <!-- SCROLL TO TOP -->
 <div class="scroll-top-wrapper">
  <span class="scroll-top-inner">
   <img src="../images/misc/scroll_to_top.svg" onmouseover="this.src='../images/misc/scroll_to_top_hover.svg';" onmouseout="this.src='../images/misc/scroll_to_top.svg';" />
  </span>
 </div>

 <!-- LIGHT-COLORED BORDER -->
 <div class="border_background">
      ....
```

Comment: Nothings really clear from your snippet as there are two images with local src. please provide a fiddle with proper images or upload images so they can be loaded

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a reset file. or margin: 0; Remember html tags have default style rules so you have to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your image. There's a slight hairline, left in the original image, when you edited this image. So try to re-edit the image and remove that hairline.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution. Apparently the "fit selected object to artboard" in adobe illustrator isn't 100% precise.